Can't access hidden table column within tablelayout layout: Android Kotlin
I create TableLayout and its rows dynamically. Also, I have a hidden column in the table. Every time I try to access the hidden column's value, I simply can't find it, even though it is supposed to be there. I have total of 3 columns in my TableLayout; column 1 index is 0 <---hidden, column 2 index is 1 and column 3 is index 2.
Here is XML for rows.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/idautoint"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:visibility="invisible" /> <------- Look over here

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="start" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="start" />
</TableRow>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

The following code is a test and it does compile. It retrieves value from the row and the column you want and displays it. However,
            val tableRow = stableLayout.getChildAt(0) as TableRow
            val cIdout = tableRow.getChildAt(0) as TextView
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, cIdout.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

What this code should show is the value from the first row and hidden first column, but it doesn't the value it displays is for the 2nd column from the left. It is as if the hidden first column doesn't exist, even though it should be there. When I add view or tablerow into tablelayout, I include the first column which is hidden.
Why is it I can't get access to hidden column?

Are you sure that you're setting the correct value on that TextView in the first place? Did you try using tableRow.findViewById() instead of getChildAt()? Also, if I correctly understand what you're doing here, it's a bit overkill to use a whole View just to hold a single primitive value. It's probably best to track that separately – e.g., in a Map<Int, View> – but if you really want to keep it in the hierarchy, you could set it as a tag on the TableRow instead of creating a TextView for it. For example, tableRow.tag = id, then val id = tableRow.tag as? Int ?: -1 to retrieve.

The issue with accessing the hidden column in your TableLayout is because setting the android:visibility attribute of the TextView to invisible doesn't remove it from the layout hierarchy
While the view becomes invisible, it still occupies its position in the TableRow.
Here's why you can't access the hidden column using getChildAt(0):
Index Order: getChildAt(0) retrieves the first visible child of the TableRow. Since the first TextView is invisible, the second TextView (with the name) becomes the first visible child with an index of 0.
u can

Maintain Child Order, that is instead of relying on the index, iterate through all children of the TableRow:
val tableRow = stableLayout.getChildAt(0) as TableRow
for (i in 0 until tableRow.childCount) {
val child = tableRow.getChildAt(i)
if (child.id == R.id.idautoint) {
val hiddenValue = (child as TextView).text.toString()
break
}
}

Use a Custom Layout:


Create a custom layout (e.g., a LinearLayout) that holds the three TextViews, with the hidden one positioned first.
Add this custom layout to the TableRow instead of individual TextViews.
This way, the hidden TextView remains at index 0 within its parent custom layout, and you can access it using getChildAt(0) on the custom layout.
